# VBA Excel Forms | renamed labels and inputboxes became corrupted

Tags: excel, vba, forms, naming, corruption

I have created a **form** that contains one main **multipage** and each 4 pages of it contains 1-1 further multipage with 2 pages.
Each of these pages (alltogether 8) contain 10 labels and 10 **inputBoxes**.
I have **renamed** the first 10 of them to test manipulating them via **_Enter** in code.
It was working fine.
Then completed renaming the rest (**160 objects**) to folow my naming logic, like: `I_2_List_Inp_1`. 
After i was done, nothing worked anymore:
Some of the boxes **regained their OLD names automatically**, but also the given name is still visible in object explorer (and neither works to do anyting with them - "ObjectRequired").
 
Moreover if I launch the form, it starts on Page2 and stucks there. I cannot move the form to any other page. 
Any idea what this can be? How to resolve it most time efficient?

Below you can see in my list as those auto-names reapperaed below my custom names, corrupting everything.
[image]

Comment: @pnuts Excel 2016.  By the way: I have now created a new blank form. Recreated the Multipage structure , and pulled all other content from the corrupted form. It seems that only the good names are copied over, and also the _enter events are working again. I have the feeling, that the nested Multipage objects played a big part in the error, but not sure. This time i will not rename the Multipages at least, leaving them as Multipage1 - 5. Let's hope it'll last.

Comment: I’d consider sub forms to limit the actual number of controls you have to draw, name and handle

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a solution but this might help: I would check the existing controls on each page, conveniently in a sub which fires when clicking anywhere on the form, like this:

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Click(ByVal Index As Long)
    For Each ctrl In MultiPage1.Pages(Index).Controls
         Debug.Print Typename(ctrl) & "," & ctrl.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

One more: garbage can make confusions. If it might happen (after a broken run or whatever) just type `End` in the immediate window or restart Excel.

Comment: I find VBA forms rather Fragile. It tends to get corrupted quite easily. Therefore I'm saving a new version backup after every modification. For this case the easyest solution was to move all content to a new blank form (as posted above) .  In one other occasion before, the corruption was caused it I reduce the formheight to 0. If you do this it gets toasted forever. (I did that because i was testing a code that enables the removal of the header ribbon of forms, and the ribbon space becomes extra whitspace, that i wanted to reduce); but this is a different story. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: sry, here: "it I reduce " i meant: "When I reduced"